# Why are Entity Framework Core Shadow Properties in the under lying query results?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In Asp.net Core using Entity Framework Core I'm adding a few Shadow Properties for things like CreatedDate, UpdatedDate, etc. that I would like to track in the database, but don't need to display to end users.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyModel>()
                .Property<System.DateTime>("CreatedDate")
                .HasColumnType("datetime2(4)")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
```

But when I do a simple select from my context

```
_context.MyModel.ToList()
```

and look at the query using Profiler, I can see those fields are in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[Field1], [r].[Field2], [r].[Field3], [r].[UpdatedDate], [r].[CreatedDate]
FROM [MyModel] AS [r]
```

Why are they included in the SQL if they aren't used in the model?  Is there a way to suppress them so I'm not returning fields from the database I know I don't need? I know I can use projections to filter out the fields but then why wouldn't I just include them in my model? Or am I not really using Shadow Properties correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You may need to provide an example of your code that produces the SQL statement.  Does using projection e.g. `.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Field1, x.Field2 })` exclude the shadow properties?

Comment: @Brad - I've updated my question. I would assume the projection would filter those fields out of the query, but I guess it just rubs me the wrong way because it feels like this is something it should inherently do, unless I'm completely missing something.